# If I build a solution from C# code, how can I tell which applications were actually built?

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have code that will build (not **re**build) an entire solution from C#.

A standard build will only compile projects which have actually changed.

After the build finishes, I'd like to know which projects were actually built.

I have tried:

1 - Looking for a changed/unchanged value (or similar) from the [BuidlResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.execution.buildresult.aspx) after the build finishes

2 - Attaching a [custom logger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.build.framework.buildeventargs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and trapping every event, then poring over the messages to see if there is any difference between changed and unchanged projects

I am really surprised that such a basic piece of information is not readily available.  For example, it seems logical that the ProjectFinishedEventArgs argument of the Logger's ProjectFinished event would contain a boolean or status value.  But if it's there, then I've overlooked it.

Does anyone know how to tell whether the product of an msbuild was recompiled or not?  I hate to resort to checking timestamps on the output binaries, but maybe that's what I'll have to do.

```
private void DoBuild()
{
  ProjectCollection pc = new ProjectCollection();
  BuildLog = new CRMBuildLogger { Parameters = _logfilename };
  Dictionary<string, string> globalProperty = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  BuildParameters bp = new BuildParameters(pc)
  {
    DetailedSummary = true,
    Loggers = new List<ILogger>() { BuildLog }
  };
  BuildRequestData buildRequest = new BuildRequestData(SolutionFileName, globalProperty, "12.0", new[] { "Build" }, null);
  BuildLog.BuildResult = BuildManager.DefaultBuildManager.Build(bp, buildRequest);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can trying looking at something like https://github.com/nagits/BuildVision and see how it's done there.

Comment: @OmarElabd I wasn't familiar with this project; but I'm checking it out now.  Looks interesting, regardless of whether it helps with this specific problem.

Comment: @OmarElabd just following up; I like this project and I'm sure I can learn a lot from it.  However, I don't think it's going to help me with this particular problem.  Although it lets you initiate a build or rebuild, I don't see anywhere that it seems aware of whether a build actually required a recompile.  I'll keep looking in case I just haven't noticed it yet.

Comment: Just curious, in Visual Studio, when you go to tools-options-projects and solutions-build and run. Do you have it set to minimal output? Try changing the output to diagnostic or verbose and set it to always show output on build. Then at the end you will be able to see what was built and what wasn't.

Comment: @JosephStyons sorry it couldn't help, but glad you like the project at least. Hope you're able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I modified my Logger class to give me what I want, but I am still hoping for a more "native" solution.  Here it is, in case anyone else finds it useful.

The general idea is to note the file modified time before the project builds, and note it again afterwards.  If it changed, assume that the project was recompiled.

I started with the [MSDN example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.build.framework.buildeventargs%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and modified these methods:

```
eventSource_ProjectStarted
eventSource_ProjectFinished
```

If you start there, then the rest should be pretty clear.  I'm happy to answer questions if anyone has them.

Even better, if someone can come along and trash this answer and say "Why don't you do X", then I'd be very happy to hear what "X" is.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Security;
using BuildMan.Classes;
using Microsoft.Build.Execution;
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;

namespace JustBuild
{
  public struct ProjectOutputTimeStamp
  {
    public string ProjectName;
    public DateTime OutputDateTime_BeforeBuild;
    public DateTime OutputDateTime_AfterBuild;
  }

  public class CRMBuildLogger : Logger
  {
    public List<string> Errors = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Warnings = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Messages = new List<string>();
    public List<ProjectOutputTimeStamp> outputs = new List<ProjectOutputTimeStamp>();

    public BuildResult BuildResult;
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize is guaranteed to be called by MSBuild at the start of the build
    /// before any events are raised.
    /// </summary>
    public override void Initialize(IEventSource eventSource)
    {
      if (null == Parameters)
      {
        throw new LoggerException("Log file was not set.");
      }
      string[] parameters = Parameters.Split(';');

      string logFile = parameters[0];
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(logFile))
      {
        throw new LoggerException("Log file was not set.");
      }

      if (parameters.Length > 1)
      {
        throw new LoggerException("Too many parameters passed.");
      }

      try
      {
        // Open the file
        streamWriter = new StreamWriter(logFile);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        if
        (
          ex is UnauthorizedAccessException
          || ex is ArgumentNullException
          || ex is PathTooLongException
          || ex is DirectoryNotFoundException
          || ex is NotSupportedException
          || ex is ArgumentException
          || ex is SecurityException
          || ex is IOException
        )
        {
          throw new LoggerException("Failed to create log file: " + ex.Message);
        }
        // Unexpected failure
        throw;
      }

      // For brevity, we'll only register for certain event types. Loggers can also
      // register to handle TargetStarted/Finished and other events.
      if (eventSource == null) return;
      eventSource.ProjectStarted += eventSource_ProjectStarted;
      eventSource.MessageRaised += eventSource_MessageRaised;
      eventSource.WarningRaised += eventSource_WarningRaised;
      eventSource.ErrorRaised += eventSource_ErrorRaised;
      eventSource.ProjectFinished += eventSource_ProjectFinished;
    }

    void eventSource_ErrorRaised(object sender, BuildErrorEventArgs e)
    {
      // BuildErrorEventArgs adds LineNumber, ColumnNumber, File, amongst other parameters
      string line = String.Format(": ERROR {0}({1},{2}): ", e.File, e.LineNumber, e.ColumnNumber);
      Errors.Add(line);
      WriteLineWithSenderAndMessage(line, e);
    }

    void eventSource_WarningRaised(object sender, BuildWarningEventArgs e)
    {
      // BuildWarningEventArgs adds LineNumber, ColumnNumber, File, amongst other parameters
      string line = String.Format(": Warning {0}({1},{2}): ", e.File, e.LineNumber, e.ColumnNumber);
      Warnings.Add(line);
      WriteLineWithSenderAndMessage(line, e);
    }

    void eventSource_MessageRaised(object sender, BuildMessageEventArgs e)
    {
      // BuildMessageEventArgs adds Importance to BuildEventArgs
      // Let's take account of the verbosity setting we've been passed in deciding whether to log the message
      if ((e.Importance == MessageImportance.High && IsVerbosityAtLeast(LoggerVerbosity.Minimal))
        || (e.Importance == MessageImportance.Normal && IsVerbosityAtLeast(LoggerVerbosity.Normal))
        || (e.Importance == MessageImportance.Low && IsVerbosityAtLeast(LoggerVerbosity.Detailed))
        )
      {
        Messages.Add(e.Message);
        WriteLineWithSenderAndMessage(String.Empty, e);
      }
    }

    void eventSource_ProjectStarted(object sender, ProjectStartedEventArgs e)
    {
      int idx = IndexOfProjectTimeStamp(e.ProjectFile);
      DateTime outputfiledatetime = DateTime.MinValue;
      StudioProject proj = new StudioProject(e.ProjectFile);
      FileInfo outputFile;
      if (File.Exists(e.ProjectFile))
      {
        outputFile = new FileInfo(proj.OutputFile());
        outputfiledatetime = outputFile.LastWriteTime;
      }

      //keep track of the mod date/time of the project output.
      //if the mod date changes as a result of the build, then that means the project changed.
      //this is necessary because the MSBuild engine doesn't tell us which projects were actually recompiled during a "build".
      //see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34903800
      ProjectOutputTimeStamp p = new ProjectOutputTimeStamp()
      {
        OutputDateTime_BeforeBuild = outputfiledatetime,
        ProjectName = e.ProjectFile,
        OutputDateTime_AfterBuild = DateTime.MinValue
      };
      if (-1 == idx)
        outputs.Add(p);
      else
        outputs[idx] = p;

      WriteLine(String.Empty, e);
      indent++;
    }

    private int IndexOfProjectTimeStamp(string projectname)
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < outputs.Count; ++i)
        if (outputs[i].ProjectName.ToUpper() == projectname.ToUpper())
          return i;
      return -1;
    }

    void eventSource_ProjectFinished(object sender, ProjectFinishedEventArgs e)
    {
      int idx = IndexOfProjectTimeStamp(e.ProjectFile);
      DateTime outputfiledatetime = DateTime.MinValue;
      StudioProject proj = new StudioProject(e.ProjectFile);
      FileInfo outputFile;
      if (File.Exists(e.ProjectFile))
      {
        outputFile = new FileInfo(proj.OutputFile());
        outputfiledatetime = outputFile.LastWriteTime;
      }

      //keep track of the mod date/time of the project output.
      //if the mod date changes as a result of the build, then that means the project changed.
      //this is necessary because the MSBuild engine doesn't tell us which projects were actually recompiled during a "build".
      //see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34903800
      ProjectOutputTimeStamp p = outputs[idx];
      p.OutputDateTime_AfterBuild = outputfiledatetime;

      if (-1 < idx)
        outputs[idx] = p;

      indent--;
      WriteLine(String.Empty, e);
    }

    public List<string> RecompiledProjects()
    {
      //let callers ask "which projects were actually recompiled" and get a list of VBPROJ files.
      List<string> result = new List<string>();
      foreach (ProjectOutputTimeStamp p in outputs)
      {
        if(p.OutputDateTime_AfterBuild>p.OutputDateTime_BeforeBuild)
          result.Add(p.ProjectName);
      }
      return result;
    } 

    /// <summary>
    /// Write a line to the log, adding the SenderName and Message
    /// (these parameters are on all MSBuild event argument objects)
    /// </summary>
    private void WriteLineWithSenderAndMessage(string line, BuildEventArgs e)
    {
      if (0 == String.Compare(e.SenderName, "MSBuild", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      {
        // Well, if the sender name is MSBuild, let's leave it out for prettiness
        WriteLine(line, e);
      }
      else
      {
        WriteLine(e.SenderName + ": " + line, e);
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Just write a line to the log
    /// </summary>
    private void WriteLine(string line, BuildEventArgs e)
    {
      for (int i = indent; i > 0; i--)
      {
        streamWriter.Write("\t");
      }
      streamWriter.WriteLine(line + e.Message);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Shutdown() is guaranteed to be called by MSBuild at the end of the build, after all 
    /// events have been raised.
    /// </summary>
    public override void Shutdown()
    {
      // Done logging, let go of the file
      streamWriter.Close();
    }

    private StreamWriter streamWriter;
    private int indent;
  }
}
```

Note that the "StudioProject" class is one that I wrote.  I don't want to post the whole thing because it has a lot of stuff that makes assumptions which would only be true in our local code base.  However, the relevant method ("OutputFile") is here.  It does a pretty dumb scan through the project file itself to figure out the output EXE or DLL.

```
public string OutputFile()
{
  if (_ProjectFile == null) return string.Empty;

  string result = string.Empty;
  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_ProjectFile);
  string projFolder = new DirectoryInfo(_ProjectFile).Parent?.FullName;
  bool insideCurrentConfig = false;
  string configuration = string.Empty;
  string assemblyName = string.Empty;
  string outputPath = string.Empty;
  bool isExe = false;
  do
  {
    string currentLine = reader.ReadLine();
    if (currentLine == null) continue;
    if ((configuration == string.Empty) && (currentLine.Contains("<Configuration"))) configuration = currentLine.Split('>')[1].Split('<')[0];
    if (!insideCurrentConfig && !isExe && currentLine.Contains("WinExe")) isExe = true;
    if ((assemblyName == string.Empty) && (currentLine.Contains("<AssemblyName>"))) assemblyName = currentLine.Split('>')[1].Split('<')[0];
    if (configuration != string.Empty && currentLine.Contains("<PropertyGroup") && currentLine.Contains(configuration)) insideCurrentConfig = true;
    if (insideCurrentConfig && currentLine.Contains("<OutputPath>")) outputPath = currentLine.Split('>')[1].Split('<')[0];
    if ((outputPath != null) && (assemblyName != null)) result = projFolder + "\\" + outputPath + assemblyName + (isExe?".exe":".dll");
    if (insideCurrentConfig && currentLine.Contains("</PropertyGroup>")) return result;        //if we were in the current config, and that config is ending, then we are done.
  } while (!reader.EndOfStream);
  return result;
}
```